# not able to send mail with attachment from linux ubuntu : 20.04 by using email mailutils (sendmail keyword)

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting, shell-scripting

code :

```
subject="Service resilience service status"
body="Service is down"
from="donotreply@domain.com"
to="user@domain.com"
attachment="/home/ubuntu/ServiceResilience/log1.log"
echo -e "Subject:${subject}\n${body}" | sendmail -f "${from}" -t "${to}" -a "${attachment}"
echo "Mail sent succesfully"
```

Error : i am getting :

```
STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message [BeginDiagnosticData]Cannot submit message.
```

Comment: That doesn’t look like a normal sendmail error. Sending mail from a Linux server requires a configured MTA like sendmail, postfix exim or similar. In addition sendmail is not really intended to be called from the cli `mail` or `mailx` works better (once your mta has been configured)